# How SUM numeric datatype postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am new  using postgresql and have problem when sum record, because give a zero result.

this my db table

```
user_id   amount
981       1200000.0000
981       -170000.0000
981       -144500.0000
981       -249800.0000
```

the amount field using "numeric" datatype
and this my query

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) as amount FROM transaction where user_id = 981;
```

how to fix this, thanks

Comment: no the user id is integer

Comment: Are you sure that the user_id is numeric?
Try enclosing 981 withing quotes. ie., '981';
Also, you'll have to use 'group by' clause, while using aggregate functions like sum()

Comment: Try this:
SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) as amt
FROM transaction where user_id = 981
group by user_id;

Comment: @Shreyas SG. thanks, the result still give the amount 0.

Comment: The query will not return 0 it will return an error. You are missing a `group by`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, no error

Comment: Then you are not using Postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, i execute the query in pgadmin.. can mysql database open in pgadmin?

Comment: There is no way the query you have shown works in Postgres: See e.g. here http://rextester.com/KGPFR24140

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sory you right.. my fault i miss write the group by the user_id in the question are you know why my sum query give zero result for amout?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with your sample data: http://rextester.com/UHG20517 There must be something you are not telling us

Comment: the sample data is clearly i just want to display user_id and sum the amount and give 1 rows result only '981','xxxx' where the amount is calculation from other rows where user id is 981.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, please look this, https://screenshot.net/lmz0mad and without sum https://screenshot.net/lm10ma3

Comment: Well, apparently the sum of all values is zero. That can absolutely happen if you mix negative and positive values: http://rextester.com/CMXSC74058

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for help :) i know now this is because mix of amount and the result right give 0 i try to in your rextester.com with complite data and the result same.